# Explanation of part of a PDF file

Tags: pdf

This segment of a PDF file seems to cause [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) to crash. [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) doesn't seem to choke on it. If I remove the `/I1 Do` and `/I2 Do` lines, the PDF file works fine. Can someone give me a quick explanation of those might be doing? Let me know if you need to see other parts of the PDF file.

```
1289 0 obj 
<<
/Length 72
>>
stream
q
360.00 0 0 583.20 0 0 cm
/I1 Do
Q
q
360.00 0 0 583.20 0 0 cm
/I2 Do
Q

endstream 
endobj
```

Comment: You may get more detailed answers if you include a link to your PDF file.

Comment: You should file a bug against poppler; see http://poppler.freedesktop.org/

Comment: @yms: I can't distribute it, unfortunately (it's a draft of a book).

Comment: @Martin Schröder: Someone filed one already, I was just curious about the PDF internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I1 and I2 are either images or form XObjects. Probably for some reason Poppler cannot decode their content and crashes. Even if I see the file I do not know the internals of Poppler so it is difficult to guess what it is causing the problem, unless it is an obvious error in the PDF structure.